# Make git ask my email every time I commit

Tags: git

I used to make git commits only with my personal email address. Now I have started working as a software developer. I want to use my work email address for my work repositories and my personal email address for personal repositories. I use `git config user.email "username@example.com"` to do this. The problem is that I have a lot of repositories and I sometimes forget to set `user.email`. Sometimes, I commit and push with the wrong email address.

Is there a way to force git to not allow me to commit if `user.email` is not explicitly set for a repository? I removed `user.email` from my global `~/.gitconfig`, but then git uses `username@hostname.local` as my commit email address.

I'm using git version 2.18.0 on MacOS High Sierra. I installed git using homebrew.

Comment: You can use [conditional includes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes) to include a different configuration file for some path. This way you can set a global email address and different other email addresses for the repos stored in certain directories (and their subdirectories). You should also set `user.useConfigOnly` to `true` to forbid Git guess the email address when it is not set.

Comment: `git config --global user.useConfigOnly true` works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [conditional includes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes) to include a different configuration file for some path. This way you can set a global email address and different other email addresses for the repos stored in certain directories (and their subdirectories). You should also set `user.useConfigOnly` to `true` to forbid Git guess the email address when it is not set.

My `~/.gitconfig` contains these sections:

```
[user]
    name = John Doe
    # The default email, used for personal projects
    email = john.doe@example.org
    # This prevents Git guess the email address if it is not set
    useConfigOnly = true

[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/"]
    path = ~/.config/git/config-work
```

The file `~/.config/git/config-work` looks like this:

```
[user]
    name = John Doe
    email = john.doe@company.org
```

It is loaded only for the repositories located in `~/work` or its subdirectories.

You can use multiple `[includeIf]` sections in your `~/.gitconfig` file if you need it. Each included file can overwrite the configuration entries listed in `~/.gitconfig` or add new entries as needed.